# ListView on Android - Populating with an ArrayList

Tags: android, sql, arraylist, android-listview, android-asynctask

I'm trying to display rows in a ListView on Android by using an SQL statement and the jTDS driver, through an AsyncTask.

**Articles.java:**

```
package com.example.projectmanager;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;


public class Articles extends AsyncTask <List<Articles>, Void, List> {

    int article_id;
    String title; 
    String body ;
    Date date;
    String username;
    List<Articles> posts = new ArrayList<Articles>();


    protected List<Articles> doInBackground(List... params) {

         Connection conn = null;
            try {   



            String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

            String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.2.2/master_db;";
            String sqlusername = "admin";
            String sqlpassword = "root";

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, sqlusername, sqlpassword);
            Log.w("Connection","open");

            String articleQuery = "SELECT TOP 5 E.article_id,E.article_title,E.article_description,E.article_date,u.username FROM articles AS E INNER JOIN user_articles as A ON A.article_id = E.article_id INNER JOIN users as u ON A.user_id = u.user_id WHERE E.article_status = 1;"; 

            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(articleQuery);

            ResultSet rs;

            rs = stmt.executeQuery();



            while (rs.next()) {

                Articles article = new Articles();
                article.article_id = rs.getInt("article_id");
                article.username = rs.getString("username");
                article.date = rs.getDate("article_date");
                article.title = rs.getString("article_title");
                article.body = rs.getString("article_description");
                posts.add(article);             


            }
            conn.close();

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
            Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
            }


        return posts;



    }
    protected void onPostExecute(List posts) {
        // Result is here now, may be 6 different List type.
        this.posts = posts; 
    }




}
```

**HomeActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.projectmanager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


        Articles a = new Articles();

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPosts);
        List postsList = null;

        try {
            postsList = new Articles().execute().get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, postsList);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 


    }


      }
```

Whenever I try to run the code I get this output:

[image]

LogCat: http://pastebin.com/cjm1BNeZ

Can anyone tell me what is going on ?

**UPDATE:** Populating the arraylist

```
String articleQuery = "SELECT TOP 5 E.article_id,E.article_title,E.article_description,E.article_date,u.username FROM articles AS E INNER JOIN user_articles as A ON A.article_id = E.article_id INNER JOIN users as u ON A.user_id = u.user_id WHERE E.article_status = 1;"; 

            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(articleQuery);

            ResultSet rs;

            rs = stmt.executeQuery();



            while (rs.next()) {

                Articles article = new Articles();
                article.article_id = rs.getInt("article_id");
                article.username = rs.getString("username");
                article.date = rs.getDate("article_date");
                article.title = rs.getString("article_title");
                article.body = rs.getString("article_description");
                posts.add(article);             


            }
```

Comment: You need to override `toString()` in your `Articles` class.

Comment: You need to turn the List into a string array

Comment: To provide any more details, we need to know how your `List` returned by `new Articles().execute().get()`; is populated.

Comment: @Code-Guru it is the return from the doInbackground() in Articles. It is populated in the Articles class (see updated question)

Comment: IMO, you should separate the `List` from the `Articles` class and rename `Articles` to `Article`. In other words, you can create a class which stores the data of a *single* article. Some *other* class should be responsible for building a list of articles from some data source (maybe a database table?). This separation will make debugging and maintaining your project *much* easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your Article class:

```
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "id: "+article_id + "\n"
                   +"title : " + title 
                   +"body: "+body ;
        }
```

Or anything other information you want your user to see.

This is because Android Framework will call YOUROBJECT.toString(); automatically to render out the object in the list. That is why you need to override this method.

UPDATE:

```
Articles article = new Articles();
                article.article_id = rs.getInt("article_id");
                article.username = rs.getString("username");
                article.date = rs.getDate("article_date");
                article.title = rs.getString("article_title");
                article.body = rs.getString("article_description");
```

This is the code where you popluate your article object. If you want to show other properties of this object in your item list. simply add the field in the toString() method.
ex:

```
  @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "id: "+article_id + "\n"
                   +"title : " + title 
                   +"body: "+body+" date"+date +"username: "+username ;
        }
```

Comment: and how would I make it possible to output all the values from the SQL query?

Comment: @Brian Since your data is from a database, you should consider using a SimpleCursorAdapter rather than an ArrayAdapter. One advantage is that it makes it easy to put each item in its own TextView rather. This way you can have columns in your ListView with headings rather than repeating the labels like "id:", "title:" etc in every row.

Answer (score 1):

I think you using ArrayAdapter wrong.
the type you put in (String) is not the type you should put.

you need to create new customized array adaper that accepts the type Articles and 
do this again.

something like:

```
    public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Articles> {

public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private List<Articles> items;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Articles> items) {

    super(context, resource, items);

    this.items = items;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {

        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);

    }

    Item p = items.get(position);

    if (p != null) {

        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.categoryId);
        TextView tt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);

        if (tt != null) {
            tt.setText(p.userName());
        }
        if (tt1 != null) {

            tt1.setText(p.getDate);
        }
        //and so on...
    }

    return v;

}
```

you should connect your views with your article object. view to attribute.
thats what adapter stands for. and string adapter is for string list only.

after this you should do:

```
ListAdapter<Articles> arrayAdapter = new ListAdapter<Articles>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, postsList);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `Articles.execute().get()` method returns a `List` of `Articles` objects. `ArrayListAdapter` calls the `toString()` method of these objects. If you do not provide your own `toString()` method, you simply inherit the default one from `Object` which prints out the class name and hash value of the object. This is why the output appears as you see it.

One way to fix this is to override the `toString()` method in your `Articles` class to return a `String` representation of the data that you want to appear in the `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

[Follow this instructions](http://sogacity.com/how-to-make-a-custom-arrayadapter-for-listview/) for a sample of a custom adpater.